# Create parent and child factory having has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Hospital and patient model. Hospital has_many relationship with patients. I have a validation check in hospital model `validates :patients, :presence => true`. After adding this validation check, rspecs for controllers are failing which are just creating hospital object. I tried to create a factory that'll create hospital and patients but no luck so far. This is what i tried so far.

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :hospital do
    hospital_id { Faker::Crypto.unique.md5 }
    name { 'something' }
    departments { 'some description' }

    after(:create) do |hospital|
      create(:patient, patient_id: hospital.id)
    end
  end
end
```

any idea what am i doing wrong?

Comment: IINM based on above, you're  _creating_  `patient` _after_ `hospital` so the validation fails since the validation _requires_  `patient` (when creating `hospital`)

Comment: I don't know if there's much value in enforcing a hospital has patients with this type of validation. As you've seen, it makes creating hospital records harder. Such a validation would not prevent you from deleting all the patient records later anyway, thus rendering your hospital invalid and unsavable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like this before; couldn't remember anymore, but can you try the following?

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :hospital do
    # ...

    after(:build) do |hospital|
      hospital.patients << build(:patient, hospital: hospital)
      # I think this needs to be assigned directly to the `hospital` object itself so that it shares the same memory space
      # when `save` is called on `hospital`, the `.patients` also get `save`d
    end
  end
end
```

If above doesn't work, can you try this instead?

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :hospital do
    # ...

    after(:build) do |hospital|
      hospital.patients.build(
        attributes_for(:patient, hospital: hospital)
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
factory :hospital do
  after :create do |hospital|
    create :hospital, patient: patient
  end
end
```

Here is a nice cheat sheet: https://devhints.io/factory_bot

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in a comment, this validation probably won't be very helpful. But I think they only way to do this is to save the hospital and patients in a single `save` call. So you probably need to add unsaved patients to the hospital association before saving the hospital. Rails will auto-save unsaved associations.

Try this:

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :hospital do
    hospital_id { Faker::Crypto.unique.md5 }
    name { 'something' }
    departments { 'some description' }

    before(:create) do |hospital|
      build(:patient, hospital: hospital)
    end
  end
end
```